# Maximum Subarray sum - Where is my solution wrong? Kadane's Algorithm

Tags: python

Here is a description of the problem:

> The maximum sum subarray problem consists in finding the maximum sum of a contiguous subsequence in an array or list of integers:
>
> max_sequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]) should be 6: [4, -1, 2,
> 1]
>
> Easy case is when the list is made up of only positive numbers and the
> maximum sum is the sum of the whole array. If the list is made up of
> only negative numbers, return 0 instead.
>
> Empty list is considered to have zero greatest sum. Note that the
> empty list or array is also a valid sublist/subarray.

My solution so far is:

```
def max_sequence(arr):
sum = 0
max = 0
for i in arr:
    sum += i


    if i > max:
        max = i
        sum = max
        

    elif sum > max:
        max = sum
    
return(max)
```

It works on simple examples but not on random ones...
Could you please help me where I made a mistake /  what I didn't consider?

[image: see the output from Codewars]

Comment: please indent the return statement into the function, and all the statements that are in the function into the function

Answer (score 0):

this may be an alternative approach of doing it:

```
def consequtive_sub_lists(l): 
    sublists = []
    for iter, item in enumerate(l):
        sublists.append([item])
        cur_sublist = [item]
        for idx in range(iter+1, len(l)):
            cur_sublist.append(l[idx])
            sublists.append(cur_sublist.copy())
    return sublists
        
            
sublists = consequtive_sub_lists([1,2,-3,4])
max_sum, max_list = max([(sum(item), item) for item in sublists])
print(f"max_sum: {max_sum}")
print(f"max_list: {max_list}")
```

output:

```
max_sum: 4
max_list: [4]
```

Some Explanations:
I sepparated the solution into 2 main steps:

- create all consequtive sub_lists out of given list (as list of lists)
- out of it, find out the element that has the maximum sum over it's elements

For the Kadane's algorithm (to make it similar to the solution in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/))

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    max = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in arr:
        sum += i
        if sum > max:
            max = sum
        if sum < 0:
            sum = 0
        
    return max
```

this one is work