# Smallest slice of a string containing all the symbols I need

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

Let's say I have a very long string that goes something like this:

```
s = '-----1---------1----2----------4----------------1--------------2---------2--3------1---3------ and so on'
```

I know that '1', '2', '3' and '4' are all found in the string. But is there a way to locate the shortest possible span within the string that would contain all four of these numbers?

Comment: Yes there is. But did you try anything and run into a specific problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't since I have no idea where to begin, nor where else to ask this question

Comment: The answer to your question is right [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-window-in-a-string-containing-all-characters-of-another-string/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```py
s = "-----1---------1----2----------4----------------1--------------2---------2--3------1---3------"
s = s.strip("-")

seqs = []
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
        seq = ""
        nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
        for c2 in s[i:]:
            seq += c2
            if c2 in nums:
                nums.remove(c2)
                if len(nums) == 0:
                    seqs.append(seq)
                    break

print(min(seqs, key=len))
```

Comment: I think that the example included only `-` in between, just to simplify more complex case

Answer (score -1):

You can do achieve it by find the minimal and maximal relevant index inside the string:

```
import itertools
s = '-----1---------1----2----------4----------------1--------------2---------2--3------1---3------ and so on'

def consequtive_sub_lists(l): 
    sublists = []
    for iter, item in enumerate(l):
        sublists.append([item])
        cur_sublist = [item]
        for idx in range(iter+1, len(l)):
            cur_sublist.append(l[idx])
            sublists.append(cur_sublist.copy())
    return sublists
strings_in = ['1', '2', '3','4']
sublists = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(s, lambda x: x not in strings_in)]
count_substrings = [len(item) if not any(True if m_str in item else False for m_str in strings_in) else item for item in sublists]
orig_sublists = count_substrings.copy()

indices = [count_substrings.index([item]) for item in strings_in]
all_mins = []
start_idx = 0
while (len(indices)!=0) and len(indices) == len(strings_in):
    cur_min = sum([num for num in count_substrings[min(indices):max(indices)+1] if isinstance(num, int)])
    all_mins.append((cur_min, [sum([num if isinstance(num,int) else 1 for num in orig_sublists[:item+start_idx]]) for item in indices]))
    if len(indices) == len(strings_in):
        start_idx += min(indices) + 1
        print()
    else:
        break
    count_substrings = count_substrings[2:]
    indices = [count_substrings.index([item]) for item in strings_in if [item] in count_substrings]
tot_min = min(all_mins)
print(f'min chars:{tot_min[0]}, minimum substring: {s[min(tot_min[1]):max(tot_min[1])+1]}')
```

output:

```
min chars:41, minimum substring: 4----------------1--------------2---------2--3
```

important to say that the silution assumes no adjacent chars from `string-in`, if it's acceptable case, the solution must modified.

kind of adaptation to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277227/maximum-subarray-sum-where-is-my-solution-wrong-kadanes-algorithm/64277667#64277667),
to achieve more efficient solution, as suggested at the same link - you can try to make an adaptation to Kadane's algorithm.

Comment: 4----------------1--------------2---------2--3 contains all the numbers and is shorter than what your script prints

Comment: didn't understand it at first, fixed in the edited answer (made the solution much more complex, as you can see). think that downvote before waiting to an answer it's not so nice..

Comment: Looks way over complicated for a simple problem

Comment: I really dont think it's a simple problem, I was also suggested you to look on a known algorithm, but will required more modification. Overall take my solution as a suggestion..

Comment: It is simple. It's possible to solve this with 10 lines of basic code like I did.